# Configure log4net for English only

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

I am using log4net. It seems it writes log based on PC-language. For some case it wrote Chinese.

Can we configure log4net, so that it writes log in English only (regardless of PC language)?

Comment: Can you share the config of log4net and the code which is writing logs to log4net?

Comment: Example of log's text you want to be "English only" could help... I.e. you don't expect exception messages to be English, do you?

Comment: yes, it would be great if exception messages in logging could always be in English, independent from the user locale